Error term, for infinite product formula, for the exponential
For this infinite product, what is the error or remainder term? Thanks!
$$\prod_{k=0}^na_k=\left(1\pm\frac{x}{2^n}\right)^{\pm2^n}$$
If x >= 0 then,
$$a_0=1+x,\qquad a_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2^{n+2}(x+2^n)}\right)^{2^n}$$
If x <= 0 then,
$$a_0=\frac1{1-x},\qquad a_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(2^{n+1}-x)^2}\right)^{2^n}$$
Python code:
import mpmath

def exp_err(x, ipow2):
    n = mpmath.mpf(2)**ipow2
    return mpmath.fabs(mpmath.exp(x) - (1 + x/n)**n)

for x in [3, 7, 15, 31, 63]:
    for iprec, ipow2 in [(64, 32), (128, 64), (256, 128)]:
        mpmath.mp.prec = iprec
        err = exp_err(mpmath.mpf(x), ipow2)
        flog2 = mpmath.log(err, 2)
        print(f"# For x={x:,} and n=2**{ipow2}, the error term is 2**{round(flog2, 8)}")

# For x=3 and n=2**32, the error term is 2**-25.50198988
# For x=3 and n=2**64, the error term is 2**-57.50198988
# For x=3 and n=2**128, the error term is 2**-121.50198988
# For x=7 and n=2**32, the error term is 2**-17.28642488
# For x=7 and n=2**64, the error term is 2**-49.28642487
# For x=7 and n=2**128, the error term is 2**-113.28642487
# For x=15 and n=2**32, the error term is 2**-3.54579322
# For x=15 and n=2**64, the error term is 2**-35.5457932
# For x=15 and n=2**128, the error term is 2**-99.5457932
# For x=31 and n=2**32, the error term is 2**21.6319388
# For x=31 and n=2**64, the error term is 2**-10.36806111
# For x=31 and n=2**128, the error term is 2**-74.36806111
# For x=63 and n=2**32, the error term is 2**69.84434708
# For x=63 and n=2**64, the error term is 2**37.84434742
# For x=63 and n=2**128, the error term is 2**-26.15565258

See also Exponential Function as an Infinite Product

Check the referenced question, my guess is that this equation is derived from
$$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty}  (1 + x/n)^n$$

Post has been edited to include definitions for a_k. X can be any number although the terms will depend on if x is positive or negative.
